# Reading data into tensorflow and creating Dataset with TF-slim

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

I need to read in many 'images' from .txt files and want to generate a tensorflow dataset with them. Currently, I read in every single matrix with numpy.loadtxt and create an array of shape [N_matrices, height, width, N_channels], and a similar array with the label for every matrix.

I create a tensorflow dataset from these two arrays by using

```
inputs = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train, dtype=tf.float32)
labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train, dtype=tf.float32)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices( {"image": inputs,"label": labels})
```

I now want to make use of the following function to create batches from this dataset (as done [here](https://github.com/mnuke/tf-slim-mnist/blob/master/model.py)):

```
def load_batch(dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, height=LENGTH_INPUT, width=LENGTH_INPUT):

    data_provider = slim.dataset_data_provider.DatasetDataProvider(dataset)

    image, label = data_provider.get(['image', 'label'])

    images, labels = tf.train.batch(
    [image, label],
    batch_size=batch_size,
    allow_smaller_final_batch=True)

    return images, labels
```

However, this gives me the following error:

> ```
> data_provider = slim.dataset_data_provider.DatasetDataProvider(dataset)
> ```
>
> File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/data/dataset_data_provider.py", line 85, in **init**
>       dataset.data_sources,
>
> AttributeError: 'TensorSliceDataset' object has no attribute 'data_sources'

Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it? I also suppose there are much better ways for handling input from txt files to tensorflow (or tensorflow-slim) but I've found very little information on this. How could I generate my Datasets in a better way?